# test a api get request

Tags: vuejs3, vitest

I would like to test a function which performs a *get* method request.

I get a network error, I set up an interception of the get method with the `spyOn()` method. I guess it is not working.

```
FAIL  src/views/__tests__/View1.spec.js > Get all data > should return
AxiosError: Network Error
```

****test**/view1.spec.ts**

```
import DataServices from "../../services/api";
import axios from "axios";
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from "vitest";

const mockGet = { data: [ { id: "1", field1: "f1", field2: "f2", "field3": "f3"}, { id: "2", field1: "f1", field2: "f2", "field3": "f3"} ] }
vi.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValue(mockGet)
describe("Get all data",()=> {
    it("should return", async function() {
        const result = DataServices.getData()
        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()
        expect(result).toHaveLength(2)
    })
})
```

**services/api.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
const apiClient = axios.create({ baseURL: '...'} })
const  DataServices = { getData() { return apiClient.get('/data') }, }
export default DataServices;
```